# Avoid heating with high current

Tags: voltage-regulator, current-measurement, heat

I am new to electronics and just tinkering with it first time. I have laptop charger with 19V/3.42A and connected to 12v regulator and 3.3v regulator to get two voltages - 12v and 3.3v. I am going to use 3.3v device(which needs upto 1A) to control 12v LED strip. But,regulator drives hot. I don't understand if it's okay or current is too high for it. Here is my circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fwE0ZA.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: 8.7V * 1A * (79 - 3)K/W = 661.2K

Comment: Have you got heat sinks on the regulators?

Comment: @LeonHeller Not yet. Will heat sink solve the problem? Is 3.42A okay with regulator and device?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams I don't understand what is 8.7 and 79? Are you saying I have to add 661.2K resistor in series with power source?

Comment: that K is for kelvin. in your setup with no heatsink the regulator would theoretically reach 660K, about 400°C.

Comment: 660K above ambient. Which is about 680degC.

Comment: Might be worth adding that this is a really horrible way to get 3.3V @ 0.5A. You are getting 1.65W out and wasting about 8W (double that at 1A!). A switching supply is the proper way to do this.

Comment: yeah @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams you got me

Comment: Heat sinks might solve the problem, but they will have to be big ones. Better to use a switcher, as suggested, or a lower voltage supply.

Answer (score 2):

A linear regulator reduces voltage by acting like a variable resistance. As a result, it dissipates energy proportional to the voltage difference times the current - in this case, (19 volts - 3.3 volts) * 500 milliamps, which is nearly 8 watts - a *lot* of heat to dissipate in a small package.

For applications like this with a large voltage difference or high power requirements, you should use a switching regulator. Switching regulators can regulate voltages up or down without wasting the bulk of the power - they operate at efficiencies as high as 90%, which means you can expect waste heat on the order of 0.2 watts instead.

Assuming this is a one-off application, you can find prebuilt switching regulator 'buck' (voltage reducing) modules on EBay quite affordably.